# QGIS data is not showing up as options when I go to Graduated option on coloring

Tags: qgis

I can’t seem to get a CSV file I added to show up as an option for column on a graduated map I added the CSV file to my shade file where do I go from here.

Comment: is  it numeric or string formatted?

Comment: I believe it is numeric

Comment: When I go to the data table you can’t edit the data I added to my map shape file and I put them in as a csv